# Zip file is corrupt in TWRP

Tags: android

TWRP and TWRP Treble give me error of "Zip file is corrupt" when I install zip roms or files. I wiped all the things that needs. (/Dalvik Cache, /System, /Data, /Cache) but nothing changed.

I redownloaded 2 or 3 times and checked the MD5 and it was all fine.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlTA3.jpg